# Regex expression help for identifying numbers with commas

Tags: python, regex

I'm learning Python and working through "Automate the boring stuff with Python". The following question is in the Regex chapter:

How would you write a regex that matches a number with commas for
every three digits? It must match the following:

- '42'
- '1,234'
- '6,368,745'

but not the following:

- '12,34,567' (which has only two digits between the commas)
- '1234' (which lacks commas)

The answer in the book is as follows:

```
re.compile(r'^\d{1,3}(,{3})*$')  #will create this regex, but other regex strings can produce a similar regular expression.
```

However when I try this, it does not recognise numbers such as 1,234. In the shell I type:

```
numRegex = re.compile(r'^\d{1,3}(,{3})*$')
```

And my searches produce the following:

```
numRegex.search('42')
```

<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='42'>

```
numRegex.search('1,234')
numRegex.search('6,368,745')
numRegex.search('1234')
numRegex.search('36')
```

<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='36'>

So it turns out the regex returns a result for values under 1000, but when the number is above 3 digits, comma or no, I get no result. Suggestions?

Adrian

Comment: Are you sure you did not make a typo? Correct is [`re.compile(r'^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$')`](https://regex101.com/r/zV9qE7/1). You missed the `\d` for *digit*

Comment: @stribizhev: Hmm...I think this should be an answer.

Comment: If it is a typo, the post should be removed. And I believe it is a typo.

Comment: @stribizhev: Ah...yep.

Comment: @stribizhev - Yep that was it. There is a typo in the book, and I am not clever enough to have found it. Well done. That extra \d made all the difference.

Comment: Please remove the post if you can.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to match numbers with a thousands delimiter, you want to fix a typo in your regex:

```
re.compile(r'^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*$')
```

Now, if you want to also match numbers without comas, you need to make it optional as well:

```
re.compile(r'^\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*$')
```

A faster version without capturing groups (faster):

```
re.compile(r'^\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*$')
```

Comment: If it is a typo, the post should be removed.